# How do I write an array of strings to an OPCUA Server?

Tags: node.js, typescript, node-opcua

This is how I'm currently trying to write an array of strings to a opcua variable on a opcua server ( attached image 2 gives attributes ). The method below takes in a string[] and tries to write this string to the variable. I can read the variable easily, with a similar method.

```
async writeFeatureName(arrayToWrite: String[]): Promise <any> {
     console.log(arrayToWrite);
     let nodesToWrite = [{
      nodeId: "ns=3;s=\"DB_ScvsInterface01".\"OUT\".\"FeatureName\"",
      attributeId: AttributeIds.Value,
        value: new DataValue({
        statusCode: StatusCodes.Good,
        value: new Variant({
          dataType: DataType.String,
          arrayType: VariantArrayType.Array,
          value: arrayToWrite
        })
      }),


    }];

    const dataValue = await this.session.write(nodesToWrite);
    winston.debug(`wrote Feature Name Array : ${dataValue.toString()}`);
    return dataValue
  }
```

When I try to write to the variable on the server, I get a type mismatch. The array is of type string[]. I've tried various recommendations, but I do not find a clear example of writing an array to an array on the server? Is this even possible ?

[this image shows the error i'm getting, which is a type mismatch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRTYL.png)

[this is the server attributes for the variable I'm trying to write to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFc05.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are using the correct technic to write an array of string to the variable.

However, the arrayDimension attribute of the variable is [60], which specifies that the variable should contain 60 element in the array.

I wonder if the arrayToWrite contains 60 elements , Can you check ?